# Datatable built with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am building a Datatable with this code:

```
 var pdatafile ="json/pdata_"+data.cmp+"_"+data.year+"_"+data.gamecode+".json";
$.getJSON(pdatafile, function (myJson) {
    let html = [];
    var i=0;
    for(let team in myJson){
        let teamName = team;
        if (i==0){ var classe='<?php echo $tvloc;?>';}
        if (i==1){ var classe='<?php echo $tvvis;?>';}
        html.push('<table class="liveboxscore"><thead>');
        html.push('<tr><th colspan="19">' + teamName + '</td></tr>');
        html.push('<tr><th colspan="2" class="'+classe+'">Player</th><th class="'+classe+'">Minutes</th><th class="'+classe+'">Points</th><th class="'+classe+'">PIR</th><th class="'+classe+'">+/-</th><th class="'+classe+'">TSR</th><th class="'+classe+'">3p</th><th class="'+classe+'">2p</th><th class="'+classe+'">1p</th><th class="'+classe+'">OR</th><th class="'+classe+'">DR</th><th class="'+classe+'">TR</th><th class="'+classe+'">Ass</th><th class="'+classe+'">TO</th><th class="'+classe+'">Bl</th><th class="'+classe+'">Rej</th><th class="'+classe+'">Foul</th><th class="'+classe+'">Drawn</th></tr></thead><tbody>');
        for(let player in myJson[team]){
            let playerName = player;
            if (myJson[team][player].threet>0) {threedata=""+myJson[team][player].threed+"/"+myJson[team][player].threet+" ("+myJson[team][player].pct3+")";}
            else if (myJson[team][player].threet==0) {threedata="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].twot>0) {twodata=""+myJson[team][player].twod+"/"+myJson[team][player].twot+" ("+myJson[team][player].pct2+")";}
            else if (myJson[team][player].twot==0) {twodata="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].onet>0) {onedata=""+myJson[team][player].oned+"/"+myJson[team][player].onet+" ("+myJson[team][player].pct1+")";}
            else if (myJson[team][player].onet==0) {onedata="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].oreb==0) {myJson[team][player].oreb="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].dreb==0) {myJson[team][player].dreb="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].treb==0) {myJson[team][player].treb="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].assist==0) {myJson[team][player].assist="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].turnover==0) {myJson[team][player].turnover="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].block==0) {myJson[team][player].block="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].rejected==0) {myJson[team][player].rejected="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].foul==0) {myJson[team][player].foul="";}
            if (myJson[team][player].drawn==0) {myJson[team][player].drawn="";}

            html.push('<tr>');
            html.push('<td>' + myJson[team][player].jpdorsal + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].pname + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].minutes + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].points + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].pir + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].pm + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].tsr + '</td><td>' + threedata + '</td><td>' + twodata + '</td><td>' + onedata + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].oreb + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].dreb + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].treb + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].assist + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].turnover + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].block + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].rejected + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].foul + '</td><td>' + myJson[team][player].drawn + '</td></tr></tbody>'); 
        }
        if (i==0){
            html.push('<tfoot><tr><td colspan="2">TOTAL</td><td></td><td>'+data.locres+'</td><td>'+data.locpir+'</td><td>'+(data.locres-data.visres)+'</td><td>'+data.loctsr+'</td><td>'+data.locthreed+'/'+data.locthreet+'('+data.locpct3+')</td><td>'+data.loctwod+'/'+data.loctwot+'('+data.locpct2+')</td><td>'+data.loconed+'/'+data.loconet+'('+data.locpct1+')</td><td>'+data.locoreb+'</td><td>'+data.locdreb+'</td><td>'+data.loctreb+'</td><td>'+data.locassist+'</td><td>'+data.locturnover+'</td><td>'+data.locblock+'</td><td>'+data.locrejected+'</td><td>'+data.locfoul+'</td><td>'+data.locdrawn+'</td></tr></tfoot>');
        }
        if (i==1){
            html.push('<tfoot><tr><td colspan="2">TOTAL</td><td></td><td>'+data.visres+'</td><td>'+data.vispir+'</td><td>'+(data.visres-data.locres)+'</td><td>'+data.vistsr+'</td><td>'+data.visthreed+'/'+data.visthreet+'('+data.vispct3+')</td><td>'+data.vistwod+'/'+data.vistwot+'('+data.vispct2+')</td><td>'+data.visoned+'/'+data.visonet+'('+data.vispct1+')</td><td>'+data.visoreb+'</td><td>'+data.visdreb+'</td><td>'+data.vistreb+'</td><td>'+data.visassist+'</td><td>'+data.visturnover+'</td><td>'+data.visblock+'</td><td>'+data.visrejected+'</td><td>'+data.visfoul+'</td><td>'+data.visdrawn+'</td></tr></tfoot>');
        }
        html.push('</table>');
        i=i+1;
    }
    document.getElementById('boxscore').innerHTML = html.join('');
});
```

Previously I include all the necessary stuff for this to work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  ref="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/jquery.dataTables.max.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/bs-3.3.6/dt-1.10.11/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/bs-3.3.6/dt-1.10.11/datatables.min.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datatables.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/livedtsets.js"></script>
```

Finally, my livedtsets.js is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var t = $('.liveboxscore').DataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,  
    "bInfo": false,  
    "bFilter": true
    });
});
```

For some reason I don't know and I am going crazy, this is not working. I mean, the table is there, but it is not a DataTable (I cannot sort the columns, etc.) Is there any problem building the datatable with js as I do?

Many thanks for your kind help.

Comment: I think you need a separate table for each team? If you know in advance how many then you're laughing and you can get DataTables to populate your tables for you rather than build them and then convert them into DataTables. Perhaps a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating on the fly the table with:

```
$.getJSON(pdatafile, function (myJson) {
```

you need to initialize your datatable at the end of the success function and not at dom ready.

Change these lines:

```
   document.getElementById('boxscore').innerHTML = html.join('');
 });
```

with:

```
  document.getElementById('boxscore').innerHTML = html.join('');
  var t = $('.liveboxscore').DataTable({
     "bPaginate": false,  
     "bInfo": false,  
     "bFilter": true
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks gaetanoM, you're in the right path, but still have some problems. As you see, there are more than one table built with the class "liveboxscore", due to the loop      "for(let team in myJson){" . There are actually two tables built. When I do what you suggest, it initialize only the first table, not the second one. How could I initialize both tables? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple tables created consecutively, and you dont know when all tables is finished, you can make your own "ready" construct like this :

```
var t, t2;
var ready = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('.liveboxscore').length && $('.anotherTable').length) {
    clearInterval(ready);
    t = $('.liveboxscore').DataTable({
      //...
    });
    t2 = $('.anotherTable').DataTable({
      //...
    });
  }
}, 10)
```

It is a simple [**interval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) that checks if the table elements exists.   If `$('.liveboxscore').length` has a value it exists in DOM. When all elements is present in DOM the interval finishes and execute `DataTable()`. Place it in your `livedtsets.js` instead of the `$(document).ready({...})`.

Comment: Thanks David, but, would you explain a little more what is this for and how it works?

Comment: @Javi, ok have updated the answer and cleared the example a little bit. The `...` was just just pointing out that you can withdraw a third, fourth and so on table if you want.